# Задание цвета Static Text c использованием WinAPI

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

На форме расположен Static Text, требуется периодически изменять цвет текста, фон остаётся исходным, дошёл до:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {

        if( ((HWND)lParam)==GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATUS_DDE) )
            {
                SetBkMode((HDC) wParam, TRANSPARENT);
                SetTextColor((HDC) wParam, RGB(0,0,255));      
            }
        return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(NULL_PEN);
    }
```

В итоге текст IDC STATUS DDE изменяет цвет на синий, но на остальных Static Text, изменился цвет фона на другой! Кто силён помогите разобраться!

Изменил код, как было рекомендовано [[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
    if( ((HWND)lParam)==GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATUS_DDE) )
        {
            SetBkMode((HDC) wParam, TRANSPARENT);
            SetTextColor((HDC) wParam, RGB(0,0,255));
            return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
        }
    else return DefWindowProc(hDlg, message, wParam, lParam);
```

Заработало почти как и требовалось, но при очередном выводе в Static Text

```
     SetDlgItemTextA (g_hwndMainForm, IDC_STATUS_DDE, szStatusDDE);
```

происходит наложение одной строки на другую, что я ещё не учёл!?

Comment: >но при очередном выводе в Static Text происходит наложение одной строки на другую, что я ещё не учёл!?

Нужно вернуть какую-нибудь кисть, отличную от `NULL_BRUSH`. Т.е. если возвращать `NULL_BRUSH`, то компонент не будет закрашивать фон вообще. А раз нет фона, значит он никогда не будет обновлен, т.е. все, что на нем рисуется, то и останется. Отсюда и результат - видны все наложения.

Comment: Если нужно, чтобы цвет фона для `IDC_STATUS_DDE` оставался без изменений, то не надо возвращать дескриптор вообще, пусть этим так же занимается DefWindowProc.

Comment: Если  использовать DefWindowProc, этом случае не меняется цвет текста!

Comment: >Если использовать DefWindowProc, этом случае не меняется цвет текста!

Можно сначала вызвать `DefWindowProc`, а потом поменять цвет текста, после чего - вернуть то, что вернула `DefWindowProc`. Или просто вернуть какой-нибудь дескриптор системной кисти, например: `::GetSysColorBrush( COLOR_BTNFACE )`

Comment: Спасибо, работают оба предложенных вами варианта!

   1. Какой вариант будет лучшим (мне кажется второй)?
   2. Если я задаю значение из системной палитры COLOR_BTNFACE (второй вариант), то будет ли правильно отображаться цвета если менять цветовые схемы в Windows?

Comment: >Какой вариант будет лучшим

Первый вариант надежнее, т.к. не требует следить за изменениями реализации компонент на системмном уровне. Второй вариант менее надежный, но возможен, если предварительно определить, какой на самом деле системный цвет у этого системмного компонента. Мне уже задавали подобный вопрос и я на него однажды ответил: [системные цвета](http://forum.vingrad.ru/index.php?showtopic=303383&view=findpost&p=2170802)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, результатом `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` должен быть дескриптор кисти, а не пера. Во вторых, Вы его возвращаете независимо от того, какой дескриптор пришел в `lParam`. Поэтому все компоненты закрашиваются одинаково. Возвращайте дескриптор в условии, а для всех остальных передавайте обработку `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` в стандартную процедуру окна.

Answer (score 0):

Вот какой вариант получился, с цветом фона самого окна:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    if (((HWND)lParam) == GetDlgItem(hWnd, 3))
    {
        SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(0, 0, 255));
    }
    return (LRESULT)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);
    break;
```